# how to create a time series column and reindex in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, reindex

How to create a column and reindex in pandas?

I'm a new pandas learner. I have 5 rows dataframe as follow:

```
   A     B     C     D
0  2.34  3.16  99.0  3.2
1  2.1   55.5  77.5  1
2  22.1  54    89    33
3  23    1.24  4.7   5
4  45    2.5   8.7   99
```

I want to replace index column 0,1...4 with new index 1 to 5. My expected output is:

```
   A     B     C     D
1  2.34  3.16  99.0  3.2
2  2.1   55.5  77.5  1
3  22.1  54    89    33
4  23    1.24  4.7   5
5  45    2.5   8.7   99
```

What I did is I create a new column:

```
new_index = pd.DataFrame({'#': range(1, 5 + 1 ,1)})
```

Then I tried to reindex:

```
df.reindex(new_index)
```

But I got error:
**`ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)`**

What should I do to reindex the former index? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `set_index`

```
In [5081]: df.set_index([range(1, 6)])
Out[5081]:
       A      B     C     D
1   2.34   3.16  99.0   3.2
2   2.10  55.50  77.5   1.0
3  22.10  54.00  89.0  33.0
4  23.00   1.24   4.7   5.0
5  45.00   2.50   8.7  99.0
```

Or set values of `df.index`

```
In [5082]: df.index = range(1, 6)

In [5083]: df
Out[5083]:
       A      B     C     D
1   2.34   3.16  99.0   3.2
2   2.10  55.50  77.5   1.0
3  22.10  54.00  89.0  33.0
4  23.00   1.24   4.7   5.0
5  45.00   2.50   8.7  99.0
```

---

Details

<sub>Original df</sub>

```
In [5085]: df
Out[5085]:
       A      B     C     D
0   2.34   3.16  99.0   3.2
1   2.10  55.50  77.5   1.0
2  22.10  54.00  89.0  33.0
3  23.00   1.24   4.7   5.0
4  45.00   2.50   8.7  99.0
```

Comment: Thanks Zero! But what if my dataframe is very big, say 800 items and probably not an array of incremental integer like ['Alice', 'bob', 'Jeff'.....'Tom']? Because it's complex, I have to use method pd.DataFrame to create a new column called new_index, is there any good way to replace the former index with this new column?

Comment: Yes, `df.set_index([newlist])`

Answer (score 3):

You need `.values`

```
df.index=df.index.values+1
df
Out[141]: 
       A      B     C     D
1   2.34   3.16  99.0   3.2
2   2.10  55.50  77.5   1.0
3  22.10  54.00  89.0  33.0
4  23.00   1.24   4.7   5.0
5  45.00   2.50   8.7  99.0
```

As Per Zero :

```
df.index += 1
```

Comment: `df.index += 1` would do.

Comment: Yea, works for me. What error do you get? Is your index type numeric?

Comment: Nice!  I learned something.  I **swear** I ran into issues with that before.  But, you're right.  It works.